# Fragment is still alive after app has been killed (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments

After I have put my app in background and locked the screen, my smartphone does a "clean in suspend" and, thus, my app is killed. After re-opening the app from `Recent Apps`, the `onCreate()` method of the main activity is called.
The strange thing is that, the last `Fragment` used before putting the app in background is "still alive". Therefore, its `onActivityCreated()` callback is called because the main activity is launched.
Is there a way to make sure that there is no fragments associated with the main activity at startup ?

Comment: *The strange thing is that, the last fragment used* - No, this is not strange ... this is normal behaviour

Comment: Ok you're right. I meant it is strange that when the app is killed, the fragment is still alive

Comment: It is not alive ... it is just reacreated

Comment: ok. Now how to prevent that from happening. I want to force it to be destroyed

Comment: There is no app closed event on Android platform ... so it is very hard to check if fragment should(configuration changed - like fx screen rotation) or should not be recreated ("app was closed" - no such thing)

Answer (score -1):

Ovveride `onDestroy()` method and stop or pause your running threads. For further details, check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#java) about android life cycle.

Comment: The onDestroy is never called.
The onDestroy of the fragment won't be called unless the onDestroy of the activity is called.
Futhermore, when the app is killed, the onDestroy of the activity is not called

Comment: I'm using `Fragment` many times and every fragments I have `onDestroy()`. for e.g. inside of my `onDestroy()`, I have closing for my `SQLite`. Also, I have logged it earlier, The `onDestroy()` logs exactly where I need it. Moving forward, I also update my answer indicating the official documentation of android life cycle

Comment: The fragment's onDestroy is called thanks to the call of onDestroy of the activity (when the user removes the app from the recent apps tab for example).

Or do you manually destroy the fragment ?

Comment: for example i have 2 fragments, on if i'm done on the fragmentA, when calling `onDestroy()` in it, It will automatically destroys fragmentA and move to fragmentB

Comment: How onDestroy is called ? You just manually call onDestroy ??